# The category of finite abelian groups has no (nonzero) projective objects.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, category-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

This is a proof verification post about the following statement:

> The category of finite abelian groups has no nonzero projective objects.

Similar questions: [About finitely generated abelian groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2526568/projective-and-injective-objects-in-the-category-of-finitely-generated-abelian-g) and [about (all) finite groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2526568/projective-and-injective-objects-in-the-category-of-finitely-generated-abelian-g).

---

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$
First we make the following observations for objects in any abelian category:

> **Observation 1.** Let $A = B \oplus C$. If $A$ is projective, then so is $B$.

(The proof is essentially as the proof that a direct summand of a free module is projective.)

> **Observation 2.** Suppose $P$ is projective. Then, any exact sequence of the form $$A \to P \to 0$$ splits.

(Use projectivity to lift the map via $P \xrightarrow{\operatorname{id}_{P}} P$.)

Now, by the Structure Theorem for Finite Groups, it suffices to show that $\mathbb{Z}/p^{n}$ is not projective for any prime $p$ and $n \ge 1$. To this end, consider the exact sequence
\begin{equation*} 
 \mathbb{Z}/p^{n + 1} \xrightarrow{p} \mathbb{Z}/p^{n} \to 0.
\end{equation*}
Since $\mathbb{Z}/p^{n + 1}$ cannot be written as a direct sum of nontrivial cyclic groups, it follows that the above sequence does not split. In turn, it follows that $\mathbb{Z}/p^{n}$ is not projective.

---

**Question:** Is the above correct?

Comment: Looks very good to me.

Comment: See also [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2528397/a-be-a-nonzero-finite-abelian-group-then-a-is-not-a-projective-or-injective). The proof by egreg is the same there.

Comment: Hi @DietrichBurde: I had seen that question but I didn't think it would apply since the category is different. Although, now that I see that answer more closely, I think the point is that it works because the objects used by egreg are actually finite abelian groups?

Comment: @DietrichBurde: No, I understood that but my point is that there egreg has shown that $\Bbb Z/p^n$ is not projective in the category of *all* $\Bbb Z$-modules. However, it is be possible that an object $P$ is projective in a subcategory but not in a larger category. Does that make sense?

Comment: OK, but here it follows the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a direct factor of a projective is projective, it is enough to show that for $p$ prime and $n\ge 1$, $\mathbf{Z}/p^n\mathbf{Z}$ is not projective in this category. Indeed, it is quotient, but not direct factor, of $\mathbf{Z}/p^{n+1}\mathbf{Z}$.

This works with no modification, more generally for the category of finite length modules over a PID which is not a field.